# Install puma on ubuntu (rubinius 2.1.1)

Tags: rvm, puma, rubinius

I am trying to install puma on ubuntu 12.04 with rubinius 2.1.1 and I am getting to following error:

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing puma:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
/home/meir/.rvm/rubies/rbx-2.1.1/bin/rbx extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
compiling io_buffer.c
compiling http11_parser.c
compiling puma_http11.c
compiling mini_ssl.c
In file included from mini_ssl.c:3:0:
/home/meir/.rvm/rubies/rbx-2.1.1/vm/include/capi/ruby/backward/rubyio.h:1:2: warning: #warning use "ruby/io.h" instead of "rubyio.h" [-Wcpp]
linking shared-object puma/puma_http11.so
make: clang: Command not found
make: *** [puma_http11.so] Error 127
```

I tried to re-install the rvm, rbx, and the following libraries: libcurl4-openssl-dev, openssl, libgnutls-openssl27.

But i get the same error.

```
ruby -v
rubinius 2.1.1 (2.1.0 be67ed17 2013-10-18 JI) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, because the ubuntu installation was 64 bit, so the libssl-dev was 64 bit, and puma gem on rubinius can't work with 64 bit openssl native extensions, so, I created another virtual machine with ubuntu 32 bit and everything works just fine.

Thanks anyway...